# STM32F373 SDADC Hal - Why use uint32_t type for pData in HAL_SDADC_Start_DMA in SIngle end zero reference mode?

Tags: stm32, hal

I'm new in Code, I try to learn with STM32F373's SDADC using Hal library. In  [AN4207 - Getting started with STM32F37x/38x SDADC](https://www.st.com/resource/en/application_note/dm00070480.pdf), page 9/28 crop below:

[image: SDADC]

Converted value's range go from -32767 to +32767 so this range need to be int32_t, right?

Here I crop from [UM1786 - Description of STM32F3 HAL](https://www.st.com/resource/en/user_manual/dm00122016.pdf) page 603

[image: HAL]

This library use uint32_t type for converted data.

So my question is Why Hal use uint32_t instead of int32_t to store negative value?

Thanks

P/S: My code:

```
__IO int16_t SDADC1_Values[SDADC1_BUFFER_SIZE];

HAL_SDADC_Start_DMA(&hsdadc1, (uint32_t*) SDADC1_Values, SDADC1_BUFFER_SIZE);
```

Comment: Good question, I too would like to know how the DMA is loading uint32_t samples into an int16_t buffer. Wouldn't this require twice the buffer length? And how is this device converting int16 ADC samples into uint32_t?

Answer (score 0):

It does not matter what type you use here. To be honest it should be `void *` to avoid stupid unnecessary warnings.

Comment: This answer is not constructive. Please explain why it does not matter.